# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException unclear

Tags: java, string, for-loop, stringindexoutofbounds

My goal is to return a string that is composed of each letter as long as the letter is later on in the alphabet than its previous one, assuming the word is lowercase. Problem is, I can't even test this out because I am getting an error (in the title) and I am unsure of how it is occurring. May I have some assistance?

Here is my code:

```
class Main {
    static String alphabetical(String str)
    {
      String alpha="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      String betical="";
        for(int k=0;k<str.length();k++){
          for (int i=0;k<alpha.length();i++){
            if(str.charAt(k)>=alpha.charAt(i)){
              betical+=str.charAt(k);
            }
          }
        }
        return betical;
    }
    //test case below (dont change):
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(alphabetical("adatplqzh")); //result should be "adtz"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume `for (int i=0; k< alpha.length(); i++)` should be `for (int i=0; i < alpha.length(); i++)`

Answer (score 2):

As per comment you should change `for (int i=0; k< alpha.length(); i++)` to `for(int i=0; i< alpha.length(); i++)`
and the modify your condition,

```
 if(str.charAt(k)==alpha.charAt(i)){    
                   betical+=str.charAt(k);
                }
```

and it will give the required output

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistype "k." Another problem however is when I change 
str.charAt(k)>=alpha.charAt(i)
to
str.charAt(k)==alpha.charAt(i)
it just returns the input "adatplqzh""

Comment: @Christopher  make a `int pos=0;` out side of both loops and change the inner loop to `for (int i=pos;i<alpha.length();i++){
            if(str.charAt(k)==alpha.charAt(i) ){    
                    betical+=str.charAt(k);
                    pos=i;
                 }
           } `

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop looks wrong,

```
for (int i=0;k<alpha.length();i++){
```

should be `for (int i=0;i<alpha.length();i++)`